# Start and stop a counter according to reactive programming

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have two buttons, one button initializes a counter and other stops the counter.
I implemented a function according to the imperative programming and another function with observables, following the declarative programming.

However, I am not satisfied with the code in the declarative way since it has side effects and global parameters.

Is there a way to implement this functionality without side effects and global parameters according to the functional reactive programming?

```
function exercise_pause_play_observable__imperative() {
    const btnStart = document.querySelector('#btnStart');
    const btnStop = document.querySelector('#btnStop');
    const timer1 = document.querySelector('#timer1') as HTMLDivElement;

    let isEnabled = false;
    let cant = 0;
    let int1: number;
    btnStart.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            isEnabled = true;
            int1 = setInterval(() => {
                cant++;
                timer1.textContent = cant.toString();
            }, 1000)
        }

    });
    btnStop.addEventListener('click', () => {
        isEnabled = false;
        clearInterval(int1);
    });
}

function exercise_pause_play_observable__declarative()  {
    const btnStart = document.querySelector('#btnStart');
    const btnStop = document.querySelector('#btnStop');
    const timer1 = document.querySelector('#timer1') as HTMLDivElement;

    let isEnabled = false;
    let cant = 0;
    let int1: number;

    const clickStart$ = fromEvent(btnStart, 'click').pipe(
        tap(e => {
            if (!isEnabled) {
                isEnabled = true;
                int1 = setInterval(() => {
                    cant++;
                    timer1.textContent = cant.toString();
                }, 1000);
            }
        })
    );
    const clickStop$ = fromEvent(btnStop, 'click').pipe(
        tap(e => {
            isEnabled = false;
            clearInterval(int1);
        })
    );

    merge(clickStart$, clickStop$);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button id="btnStart">START</button>
    <button id="btnStop">STOP</button>
    <div id="timer1"></div>


    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574634/cancel-an-observable-created-with-fromevent-and-switch-to-a-new-one/56576425#56576425 
this question should help, very similar

Comment: @FanCheung Almost similar question, but how do I interrupt the `interval `and, when I clic, continue from the number where it was last emit?

Comment: @FanCheung `scan(acc => acc + 1, 0),` I added the scan operator between the mergeMap and distinctUntilChanged operators... It seems that it works

Comment: Ya that will work. I also added a  answer. Very minimal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do achieve what you wanted. Store the count inside `defer()` or `scan`. Probably the simplest form that I can think of.

```
const start$=fromEvent(document.querySelector('#start'),'click')
const stop$=fromEvent(document.querySelector('#stop'),'click')
    defer(()=>{
        let count=0;
        return interval(1000).pipe(
          windowToggle(start$,()=>stop$),
          exhaustMap(obs=>obs),
          map(_=>count++)
        )
    }).subscribe(console.log)

    // or
     interval(1000).pipe(
      windowToggle(start$,()=>stop$),
      exhaustMap(obs=>obs),
      scan((acc,curr)=>++acc,0)
    ).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was going to choose this as the answer, but @user2216584 came up with a more elegant solution. Thanks for helping me in the reasoning, though

Comment: Well, I marked this as the answer because the @user2216584 response has a problem with pressing the start button several times consecutively

Comment: thanks. I tested solution in stackbliz, but forgot to save it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interval that is cancelled by a subject called stop$ with takeUntil.

```js
const { Subject, fromEvent, interval } = rxjs;
const { takeUntil } = rxjs.operators;

const stop$ = new Subject();

fromEvent(document.getElementById('btnStart'), 'click').subscribe(() => {
  stop$.next(); // If restarting make sure the old one is cancelled
  const timerDiv = document.getElementById('timer1');
  timerDiv.innerText = '';
  interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(stop$)).subscribe(val => {
    timerDiv.innerText = (val + 1);
  });
});

fromEvent(document.getElementById('btnStop'), 'click').subscribe(() => {
  stop$.next();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnStart">START</button>
<button id="btnStop">STOP</button>
<div id="timer1"></div>
```

Comment: Mmmm maybe the problem here is that the observer has a too much logic, is there a way for the operators to giving to the observer the value it expects?

Comment: There are 3 observers here and the one that updates the timer could not be simpler, it gets the val and updates a div with it.

Comment: I tested the code, but this restarts from 0 everytime when you clic start, the idea is to resume from the last emitted value

Answer (score 0):

How about to implement like this:

Start the interval as soon as the user clicks "Start" button and and on click of stop button emit `NEVER`. Also keep track of last emitted value using `scan` operator. Let's code this statement in rxjs like this:

```
const btnStart = document.querySelector('#btnStart');
const btnStop = document.querySelector('#btnStop');
const timer1 = document.querySelector('#timer1') as HTMLDivElement;

//button start observable maps to true
const btnStart$ = fromEvent(btnStart, 'click').pipe(mapTo(true));

//button stop observable maps to false
const btnStop$ = fromEvent(btnStop, 'click').pipe(mapTo(false));

merge(btnStart$, btnStop$)
.pipe(
  switchMap(isStart => {
    return isStart ? interval(500) : NEVER;
  }),
  //this will start your interval from where you last stopped
  //i.e. keep track of last emission when stop was clicked
  scan(acc => ++acc),
  tap(interval => {
    timer1.textContent = `${interval + 1}`;
  }),
).subscribe();
```

Working Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-uywbc6?file=index.html

Notice we are not saving any temporary state to keep track of last emission. We are using `scan` operator to do that [i.e. Let rxjs does that for us].

Comment: However, by pressing the Start button several times consecutively, the counter stops (like a debounce). What should happen, is that the counter should continue to progress normally without restarting it.